# Remain on tab after HTTP post request in Django

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, http

I am working on a registration form (login and signup) for a website for a client.

It looks something like this:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-tabbed-login-and-signup-register-forms-interface

I implemented it, per request, as two tabs, one for login and the other for signup.

I use django forms to create the forms at the server and use templates to capture errors
something like this for example:

```
                            {% if respErrors %}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">    
                                    <strong>Errors:</strong>
                                    <ul>
                                        {% for error in respErrors %}
                                        <li class ="errorLi">{{ error }}</li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %} 
                            <p>                                 
                                <label for="{{loginForm.username.id_for_label}}" class="nonBool"> Your Email or Username </label>
                                {{ loginForm.username }}
                                {% if loginForm.username.errors %}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">                                    
                                    {{ loginForm.username.errors }}
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </p>
```

My issue is that when I am on the second tab, in this case the signup and say I submit the form and there was an error, the views.py returns as follows:

```
return render(request,
                      "register.html",
                      {'loginForm': loginForm,
                       'signupForm' : signupForm })
```

The problem is that gets the focus back on the first tab, how can I keep the second tab in focus so you don't have to click the second tab again to see the errors under the fields with bad inputs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change the following divs according to the respective error:
`<div class = "tab-pane fade" id="login">`, `<div class="tab-pane active in" id="create">`. Also, you have to set the `class = 'active'` in the respective `<li>`. In your particular case, try the following:

First:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     {% if signupForm.errors %}  
        <li><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
        <!-- set the Create Account tab as active -->
        <li class = 'active'><a href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Create Account</a></li>
     {% else %}  
        <!-- set the Login tab as active -->
        <li class = 'active'><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Create Account</a></li>
     {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Then do this in the `<div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">` line:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
{% if signupForm.errors %}  
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="login">
{% else %}  
            <!-- show the login tab -->
            <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
{% endif %}
```

Finally, do this in the `<div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">` line:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
{% if signupForm.errors %}  
            <!-- show the create account tab -->
            <div class="tab-pane active in" id="create">
{% else %}  
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
{% endif %}
```

**Note:** Please ignore the `<!-- language: lang-html -->` lines, I'm new to Stackoverflow and didn't know how to specify html sintax for my answer.